# What does it mean when I get rows executed, but with no resulted table?

Tags: qgis, postgis, pgrouting

While applying the following tutorial: http://anitagraser.com/2011/02/09/creating-catchment-areas-with-pgrouting-and-qgis/ utilizing vector network which has been tested (and demonstrated functionality) for shortest path application, it returned the following message:

> Query returned successfully: 1013 rows affected, 199 ms execution time

but returned no table as output!

The code I used is:

`create table catchment_1 as
select
    id,
    the_geom,
    (select sum(cost) from (
       SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra(
    'SELECT id, source, target, st_length(geom) as cost FROM schema.cvl',
    1, 320, false, false
  )) as foo ) as cost
from schema.cvl_vertices_pgr`

I also tried passing "id" to the function instead of "320" as per the tutorial but got the following msg:

> ERROR: function pgr_dijkstra(unknown, integer, bigint, boolean, boolean) does not exist SQL state: 42883

Although, pgr_dijkstra is working well with other codes.. so, it's one of the recognized functions in my installed pgRouting layer

I'm using QGIS 2.0.1 and pgRouting pg93-binaries-2.4.0

Comment: Feels like some syntax error but I can't see where. Biggest difference to the reference is in `FROM schema.cvl`. The example was without schema and the ANSI syntax would be `FROM "schema"."cvl"` I would test the inner SELECT first and add more flesh once I know that the core works OK.

Comment: Thanks.. I followed your recommendation and added the quotes. Same number of rows resulted but time of processing increased. Still there is no output table

Comment: Did you remove already all the decorations and test with the inner ` SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra( 'SELECT id, source, target, st_length(geom) as cost FROM schema.cvl', 1, 320, false, false )` ? About your question What does it mean... It probably means that many rows are processed but SELECT does not select anything so there is nothing to write into the table and it stays empty.

Comment: I started by the inner SELECT then went up step by step.. I got result table for each step until I reached the highest SELECT in the structure.. I got a table showing the cost for each point_id. the special result is a point feature.. but what drew my attention in the result table is that all costs are exactly the same '32430.028' whereas the points are non-regularly distributed..

This means that I just needed to remove 'create table catchment_1 as' to get a result table, but still the cost values do not seem to make sense

Comment: Sorry, I have never used pgRouting but at least you have made some progress.

Comment: Thank you for the support.. it is a considerable progress.. please refer to my question if you know someone who is knowledgeable of pgRouting

Comment: just a guess here but do you actually have a schema called schema?

Comment: Yes.. in this schema, there is network vector feature called CVL, and points feature called CVL_VERTICES_PGR